# Probabilistic puzzle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

There are $n+1$ boxes and every box contains $n$ balls. For every
$k\in\left\{ 0,1,\ldots,n\right\} $ there is exactly $1$ box containing
$k$ white balls and $n-k$ black balls. A box is picked out and $m$
balls are taken out. Here $m<n$ so the box is not empty yet. All
balls that are taken out appear to be white balls. Now another ball is taken out of that same box.
What is the probability that it is a white one?

I allready have an answer of myself, so am not in the need of one. I just like this 'puzzle', and maybe so do you. Next to that I am interested in answers that are 'nicer' than mine. It is beyond doubt that they exist.

Comment: What do *you* think? How do you approach the problem? What answer do you get?

Comment: @GerryMyerson presumably the [puzzle] tag implies that the OP already has the solution, but figures the problem would interest others.

Comment: @Jonathan, maybe so, but, if so, OP ought to say so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay I will say that. I am not very familiar with the rules here. My apologies for that.

Comment: It is hard for me to tell whether my answer is nicer than yours, when you keep your answer to yourself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My aim is not that you can tell that, but that I can tell that. What should I do then? Ask this question and at the same time give my answer? Then it is as if I am saying: 'Hey guys, look what I did... Nice isn't it?' I dislike that. By the way, just give me your answer and I will let you know wether it is nicer than mine. You are not the judge then, but that makes it even better, doesn't it? Also we can arrange somehow that you will get the disposal of my answer, but first I want to see yours.

Comment: I'm not here to play games.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I respect that and nobody forces you to play games here. It is no more than a polite invitation. This is my last comment.

Comment: Since "nicer" is undefined, this is not a real question.

Comment: @Did If I would have left out the sentence 'I am interested  in nicer answers' would it then be a question? I only express my interest there. You can reason whether it is a question or not, but in my view the answer to that is not depending on the use of the word 'nicer' here. If people qualify it as a puzzle then I agree. In puzzles questions are asked.

Comment: From the description of the [tag:puzzle]: *If the answer is known to you please do not use this tag to "riddle" other users, but rather to ask about the correctness of a possible solution or ways to extend and improve an existing solution.* I suggest putting your solution in and asking for comments on it. If it is short, you can prepended it with `>!` (hidden, but visible on mouse-over). Unfortunately, `>!` doesn't work with more than one paragraph.

Comment: @VedranŠego thank you for advice. In fact I was busy publishing my answer allready, and having done that I saw your comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson here is my answer.

Comment: @did I have decided to publish my answer.

Comment: No problem. Given that it's a bit long answer, this is probably a better form anyway, although it reduces the chance for you to get any more answers. Personally, I don't mind "puzzles to which the OP has an answer", even without the answer, but this must be stated properly (as you did in your edit) and tagged accordingly (for which [tag:puzzle] is wrong; I don't know if there is an appropriate one, but you can suggest it on Meta if there is none).

Comment: OK. Now there is a question.

Comment: @donantonio I have published my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can go one step further than your own second answer and derive not just the intermediate result $P(W_m)=\frac1{m+1}$ but also the final result $P(W_{m+1}\mid W_m)=\frac{m+1}{m+2}$ purely by symmetry without calculation.

As in that answer, consider a box with $n+1$ balls in a row where the first ball drawn determines the border between white and black balls among the remaining $n$ balls. As you say, the probability for drawing $m$ white balls is the probability for that border ball to be the last of these $m+1$ balls in the row, and thus by symmetry $\frac1{m+1}$. But if we then draw another ball, it is equally likely to be inserted into the order of these $m+1$ balls at any of the $m+2$ possible places, and only one of these places it beyond the border ball and thus among the black balls, so the probability for this is $\frac1{m+2}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had something like that in mind also but had not worked it out yet. Thank you. Symmetry is really beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

I liked the puzzle, and your elegant solution of it. 
One possibly more direct, or at least somewhat informative, approach 
is to look at the puzzle's continuous counterpart. 
Thus, corresponding to the set of $n+1$ urns let ${\bf P}$ 
be a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable one realization 
${\bf P}=p$ of which is used to perform $m$ independent Bernoulli trials, 
each with success probability $p$. 
Let ${\bf S}_m$ be the number of successes in these $m$ trials. 
Then ${\sf P}({\bf S}_m=m) \; = \; \int_{0}^{1}\, p^m \, dp \, = \, \frac{1}{1+m}$, 
exactly as in the discrete urn case. 
Also, using Bayes' Theorem the posterior density of ${\bf P}$ given that 
${\bf S}_m=m$ is then directly seen to be 
${\sf P}({\bf P} = p | {\bf S}_m=m) \, = \, f_{P}(p) \, = \, (1+m) \, p^m$. 
This in turn implies that given ${\bf S}_m=m$ the $(m+1)-$th Bernoulli 
trial results in a further success with probability 
$\int_{0}^{1}\, p \, f_{P}(p) dp \, = \, \frac{m+1}{m+2}$, 
again exactly corresponding to the discrete urn case. 
Of course, one may still search for an even ``more direct'' approach.

Comment: Very nice approach(+1)! It really confirms my presumption that some other route was possible here.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to publish here my own answer. This also because of the comments that were given to my 'question'. Also I have decided not to do this anymore. I do not want to do things here that other people rather see not happen.

Denote the event that the box picked out contains exactly $k$ white
balls by $D_{k}$.

Denote the event that the $m$ balls taken out
are all white by $W_{m}$.

Then:

$$P\left(W_{m}\right)=\sum_{k=m}^{n}P\left(W_{m}|D_{k}\right)P\left(D_{k}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=m}^{n}P\left(W_{m}|D_{k}\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=m}^{n}\left({k\atop m}\right)\left({n-k\atop 0}\right)\left({n\atop m}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left({n\atop m}\right)^{-1}\sum_{k=m}^{n}\left({k\atop m}\right)$$

With induction we find easily that: $$\sum_{k=m}^{n}\left({k\atop m}\right)=\left({n+1\atop m+1}\right)$$
So:

$$P\left(W_{m}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\left({n\atop m}\right)^{-1}\left({n+1\atop m+1}\right)=\frac{1}{m+1}$$

Then: $$P\left(W_{m+1}|W_{m}\right)=P\left(W_{m+1}\cap W_{m}\right)/P\left(W_{m}\right)=P\left(W_{m+1}\right)/P\left(W_{m}\right)=\frac{m+1}{m+2}$$

So the answer is:

> $$P\left(W_{m+1}|W_{m}\right)=\frac{m+1}{m+2}$$

Especially the 'nice' equality $P\left(W_{m}\right)=\frac{1}{m+1}$ makes me think that a more direct route to that result exists. If there is one then please let me know, and thanks for that in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended my original answer with:

> Especially the 'nice' equality $P\left(W_{m}\right)=\frac{1}{m+1}$ makes me think that a more direct route to that result exists. If there is one then please let me know, and thanks for that in advance.

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3515207/75923) I finally (more than $6$ years later) found an answer for that.

---

I use a new setup that actually is the same as the original one.

Instead of choosing one box out of $n+1$ boxes we use one box and then choose uniformly how many of the balls in it are white.

---

Let there be a box containing $n+1$ balls.

For convenience we label the balls with the numbers $1,2,\dots,n+1$.

We take out randomly $m+1$ balls one by one and denote the drawn
numbers by $X_{0},X_{1},\dots,X_{m}$.

After drawing the first ball, the balls with a number less than $X_{0}$
are painted white and all other remaining balls are painted black.

Then we go on with drawing the other balls.

If $Y$ denotes the number of white balls among the balls with labels $X_{1},\dots,X_{m}$
then by symmetry it is evident that $Y$ has uniform distribution
on $\left\{ 0,1,\dots,m\right\} $.

Then: $$P\left(Y=m\right)=\frac{1}{m+1}$$ and the event $\left\{ Y=m\right\} $
corresponds with the event $W_{m}$ mentioned in my original answer.